# Randomly get: gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: ppa, docker, gnupg, keyserver

I want to add new repositories on Ubuntu 18.04 and randomly get the following error:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

Randomly, as in, the same command sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. When it doesn't, I just rerun it and eventually it works.

I've seen related questions, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351783/nonzero-error-code-on-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-cannot-assign-requested-a) but there are no satisfactory solutions. I didn't have this problem is the last few weeks, so something must have changed. On my side I believe nothing has changed, there are no reports that the keyserver is down or degraded, so I'm at a loss...

### To reproduce this issue using docker:

1. Run `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04`
2. In the docker container, run: `apt update && apt install gnupg2 -y`
3. Try to add the repository key, this one is from ROS Spanshot: `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4B63CF8FDE49746E98FA01DDAD19BAB3CBF125EA`, you may also try the key to Git PPA repository: `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A1715D88E1DF1F24`

The last step often fails with:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.FhnZLWMBd1/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4B63CF8FDE49746E98FA01DDAD19BAB3CBF125EA
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
```

But if I rerun the same command, it will eventually work and output:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.x0bEOm55IF/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4B63CF8FDE49746E98FA01DDAD19BAB3CBF125EA
gpg: key AD19BAB3CBF125EA: public key "ROS Spanshot builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EOSS (*end-of-standard-support*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specifically about moving to a *fully supported* release of Ubuntu. Being EOSS, mirrors can drop the release.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/

Comment: So what about questions on EOSS release? The question was raised probably because the user had to use that version for his own reason. We're looking for an answer, not for an official support. Is askubuntu.com sponsored by Canonical who told you not to support users of a EOSS release? @guiverc

Comment: @Robert read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where it says only *currently supported* release and *official flavors*.  As far as Ubuntu is concerned, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL, with **some architectures only** having ESM or *Extended* support which is provided by Canonical (not Ubuntu or the Ubuntu community).  Ubuntu *flavors* of 18.04 actually reached EOL back in 2021-April (3 year after release), but wider *community* support extended for 5 years, thus until 2023-April  (*this site uses the wider community support as its not limited to three year flavor support*)